# Sorting by joined data Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

In my Yii2 project I have `post` and `post_views` tables, and a `Post` model.

There are 2 fields in `post_views`:

- `post_id`
- `views_counter`

I'm using `PostSearch` and `PostsQuery` (ActiveQuery) for my queries.

My Task is: I need to get all my posts with custom field `views` where I get `views_counter` from `post_views`.

I'm not using `hasMany` in model because there is no model for `post_views` table in the project and I'd prefer not to create it if possible. Also, I need to sort my posts by `views` field. I'm stuck on this:

```
public function topPosts(){
    $junction_table = '{{%post_views}}';
    return $this->innerJoin($junction_table, Post::tableName().'.id='.$junction_table.'.post_id');
}
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to join and return data properly. 
I need this query:

```
SELECT p.*, pv.views_count FROM posts p INNER JOIN post_views pv ON p.id = pv.post_id ORDER BY pv.views_count DESC;
```

Comment: Just for curiosity...can i ask why the `views_counter` colummn  isn't part of `post` table? I can't see any reason for not be.

Comment: I think there could be more columns in the future so I decided to divide them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to update your Post model with viewCount field:

```
class Post extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    private $viewCount;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return "posts";
    }

    public function setViewCount($viewCount)
    {
        $this->viewCount = $viewCount;
    }

    public function getViewCount()
    {
        return $this->viewCount;
    }
}
```

Then you need to include viewCount field in select list like this:

```
$post = new Post();
$query = $post->find()
        ->alias('p')
        ->select(['p.*', 'pv.views_count viewCount'])
        ->innerJoin("post_views pv", "p.Id = pv.id")
        ->limit(100)
        ->orderBy(["pv.views_count" => SORT_DESC]);

//Get SQL query string
echo $query->createCommand()->getSql();

//Execute query
$result = $query->all();
```

Comment: @MaximBelyaev If you want to say "thank you," vote on or [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that person's answer. Further read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)